# Bluetooth chat BluetoothService.this.start() error and mchatservice,start() error

Tags: android, bluetooth

[Bluetooth chat sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat)
[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Hi I trying out the bluetooth chat but I getting this error cannot resolve method start(); for both. Anyone know what wrong?

[BluetoothData_display Java file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1c2y7qx4u9tw9bn/BluetoothData_display.txt?dl=0)
[Bluetooth Service Java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqpn40382mks6uy/bluetoothservice.txt?dl=0)

So The BluetoothService.start() error I getting is in this Bluetooth Service java link and the mchatservice error is in this BluetoothData_display Java link. I using the Bluetooth chat sample code and I changed some of the code in it.

Comment: Can you plz include more details ? What is mChatService and BluetoothService ?

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev The code is the BluetoothChat sample. The code is quite long so I put the link to it instead.

Comment: @AndroidDev Is under Bluetoothchatfragment and Bluetoothchat service.

Comment: @AndroidDev Hi Sorry ignore the code. I forgot I modify it. I will upload another one

Comment: So you are building the code of mentioned BluetoothChat sample ,Right ?

Comment: Okay so update it, It will be more easier understand me ?

Comment: @AndroidDev Hi I uploaded the code I modified. Link above. My error is when I did BluetoothService.start() the start() is in red. Same goes for the mchatservice.start() And yes the code is based on BluetoothChat sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through the code sample you have mentioned above , I found that you have not defined **start()** (It is included in **BluetoothChatService** of sample code) method inside **BluetoothService** (Which you have uploaded on dropbox)

Here is the **start()** method of **BluetoothChatService** .Modify it according to yours.

```
public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490859/textview-values-does-not-update-when-data-received-from-arduino

Comment: @Spotty Wait I am on phone call right now . I will answer when I free .